# RxJS Throw error via NodeEventHandler in fromEventPattern

Tags: javascript, rxjs

If I am using fromEventPattern, and the custom API has a separate handler for errors, how can I throw them into the stream via the handler function (NodeEventHandler)?

```
import { fromEventPattern } from 'rxjs';

const token = someAPI.registerEventHandler(function(event) {}, function(error) {}); // API takes a second function for errors.
someAPI.unregisterEventHandler(token); 

const someAPIObservable = fromEventPattern(
  function(handler) { return someAPI.registerEventHandler(handler, handler); }, // What should be the second argument here, in order to throw the error to any subscribers
  function(handler, token) { someAPI.unregisterEventHandler(token); } 
);
```

I could call the handler with the error (as above) and then pipe the resulting observable returned from `fromEventPattern` in order to check the type but it seems a bit verbose:

```
pipe(
      map((x: unknown) => {
        if (x instanceof Error) throw x;
        return x;
      }),
```

`subject` (which I am trying to replace with `fromEventPattern`) has a specific `.error()` method. Which would avoid all of the manual piping and type checking.

Comment: You can create your own observable to wrap the eventListeners instead of using fromEventPattern, it'll be easier

Comment: @FanCheung Then I would have to manually manage unsubscribing, sharing, lazy subscribing etc. This is the intended usage of fromEventPattern from what I understand.

Comment: I am not sure if from event pattern provide interface for error handling but I would say u probably end up writing more code to adapt this method. Unsubscribe is easy just return a function, sharing just add a share operator

Comment: @FanCheung Please could you provide a simple example? I can't see how it can be much shorter than the above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this wrapper out

```
const yourEventObservable=new Observable(obs=>{
  const token=someAPI.registerEventHandler(res=>{
    if (res instanceof Error) 
       obs.error(x);
     obs.next(res)
  })
  return ()=>someAPI.unregisterEventHandler(token);
}).pipe(share())
```

Comment: Thanks there's not much difference in length and no need for the mapping outside. I'll give it a bit of time to see if anyone can find a hidden API in fromEventPattern, or otherwise mark this as the answer.